# How i can migrate a short ASP.NET WebForms Application to ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, webforms

I have a short asp.net web forms aplication, with 6 aspx pages, and 4 entityes. I using NHibernate for data operation! I need to migrate this aplication for asp.net MVC, and i never used this before. Someone know how i can do it, or if have a "ready formula" or simple tutorial for do this? I got only more 5 days for do that!

Comment: start reading an MVC tutorial , it's going to be pretty straight forward , but no , there is no tool to automatically do it for you

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest to a template I know of:
[ASP.NET Boilerplate](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/) and its [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768664/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-Boilerplate).